# sIFR: Different Font-Sizes rendered

Tags: sifr, font-size

why does my .swf-file render different font-sizes depending on the displayed content? 
I defined only one "sIFR-class". Why are there rendered different font-sizes?
See my two example links below.

- [Big font-size](http://p116900.typo3server.info/startseite/)
- [Small font-size](http://p116900.typo3server.info/aktuelle-ausstellungen/ausstellung-detail/archive/2010/maerz/article/dolor-ist-blindtext-kopie-1/?tx_ttnews%5bday%5d=11&cHash=cecef1c0a8)

Answer (score 0):

sIFR 2 does that. Try with sIFR 3 instead.

Comment: Is there no way to tell sIFR 2 NOT to do that …?

Comment: Nope. It's a fundamental difference in how sIFR 2 calculates font size versus sIFR 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that setting a height value instead of a font-size value solves this problem